# Join expected in select statement on X++

Tags: select, axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-365-operations

I'm going mad over a query I need for my project

```
    purchTable = this.purchTable;
    if (purchTable)
    {            
        str intentLetterId_IT = purchTable.IntentLetterId_IT;           
        select intentLetter.RemainAmountMST() from intentLetter
            where intentLetter.IntentLetterId == intentLetterId_IT
               && intentLetter.RecId == purchTable.RecId;    
        if (intentLetter)
        {
            Amount remainAmountMST = intentLetter.RemainAmountMST();
            info(strFmt("RemainAmountMST: %1", remainAmountMST));
        }
    }
```

I keep receveing the error

> Join Expected on the select statement

I tried something but I couldn't find the right way.

Comment: Consider accepting an answer or provide additional information.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is incorrect as X++ does not allow function expressions in the select. That is why you get a compile error.

Correct syntax is:

```
if (purchTable)
{        
    select firstonly intentLetter
         where intentLetter.IntentLetterId == purchTable.IntentLetterId_IT;   
    if (intentLetter)
    {
        info(strFmt("RemainAmountMST: %1", intentLetter.remainAmountMST()));
    }
}
```

Use `select firstonly intentLetter` which select all fields like SQL `select * from intentLetter`.
Do not select on `RecId` as they cannot be expected to match.

Or the easy way out:

```
info(strFmt("RemainAmountMST: %1", IntentLetter_IT::find(purchTable.IntentLetterId_IT).remainAmountMST()));
```

This delagates the problem of selecting to the provided function `find`.

Answer (score -1):

Either you use a join

```
select intentLetter.RemainAmountMST()
    join purchTable
    from intentLetter
        where intentLetter.IntentLetterId == intentLetterId_IT
           && intentLetter.RecId          == purchTable.RecId;
```

or you use a RecId type parameter for that purchTable.RecId like you did for intentLetterId_IT.

Comment: The syntax is incorrect, you cannot select a function.

Comment: And this is why you don't write answers while debugging your own code, kids :D